# Why does str_contains work in my Symfony project with PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

As title suggests, I am working on a Symfony project with PHP 7.4 and I have been using the PHP function `str_contains` for a while now. However today looking something up I found that this function was introduced in PHP 8.0, as explained here: https://php.watch/versions/8.0/str_contains

In my project, `str_contains` is working fine, so my question (as weird as it may sound) is: how can my code be working? Shouldn't it crash when I try to use that function?

Comment: Are you sure you're really using PHP 7.4? Try outputting the PHP version with `phpversion()`.

Comment: Your project (maybe Symfony itself?) includes some package that backports the function to PHP <8…?

Comment: Hi! `phpvesion()` outputs 7.4.30

Comment: It's called [Symfony polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/blob/main/README.md).

Comment: Experienced the same thing. `str_contains` works on my PHP 7.4.33. Not sure why. I might switch back to using `strpos` to be safe.

Comment: @Tashi in my case, this was due to my project using [Symfony polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill). Have you checked if it's the case for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been suggested in the comments by @deceze and @u_mulder, it works thanks to [Symfony polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/blob/main/README.md), which backports many functions, in particular `str_contains`, from newer versions.